# Pattern for reacting to a continuous stream only once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns

When dealing with events that involve X, Y position of the mouse or any time of data that continually gets updated, what pattern is used to react to a particular situation only once in T period?

For example if I am listening to a droppable hander through the accept option, the accept function is continually being executed to check the dropability, but how can I only pop my message to the user only once in T period without bombarding my screen with popped messages?

```
$scope.layoutDropOptions = {
    hoverClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
    multiple: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: function (elem) {
        var isAField = $(elem).hasClass("field");
        var isFromSideBar = $(elem).parent().hasClass("fields");
        var onTheSame = $(this).find('#' + $(elem).attr("id")).size() != 0;
        var alreadyExists = $('.layoutContainer').find('#' + $(elem).attr("id")).size() != 0;

        if (alreadyExists && isFromSideBar) {
            // need to pop only once:
            //toaster.pop('warning',
            //    UserMessages.formBuilder.duplicateField.title,
            //    UserMessages.formBuilder.duplicateField.body);
            return false;
        }
        return isAField && !onTheSame ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but didn't think that was too relevant to the question so didn't tag it. I want to know generally how people deal with such situations. But yes this is a directive controller not a view controller

Comment: google terms `javascript throttle` or `javascript debounce`

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, if you add this as an answer I will give you the points. Will use the lodash throttle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing this at the moment but I think perhaps someone can come up with a better way and get the points?

```
var lastCall = 0;

$scope.layoutDropOptions = {
    hoverClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
    multiple: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: function (elem) {
        var isAField = $(elem).hasClass("field");
        var isFromSideBar = $(elem).parent().hasClass("fields");
        var onTheSame = $(this).find('#' + $(elem).attr("id")).size() != 0;
        var alreadyExists = $('.layoutContainer').find('#' + $(elem).attr("id")).size() != 0;

        if (alreadyExists && isFromSideBar) {

            if (new Date() - lastCall > 1000) {
                lastCall = new Date();
                toaster.pop('warning',
                    UserMessages.formBuilder.duplicateField.title,
                    UserMessages.formBuilder.duplicateField.body);
            }
            return false;
        }
        return isAField && !onTheSame ? true : false;
    }
}
```